# What's best way to keep a ruby process run forever?

Tags: ruby

I have to run a file.rb that make a micro-task (Insert a qwuery into a database) every second.

I have used a for loop (1..10^9) but I got a CPU usage exceed alert! So what's the best way to not waste all CPU?

Comment: So your query insertion into db is leaking!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to run forever is just to loop

```
loop do
  run_db_insert
  sleep 1
end
```

If it's important that you maintain a 1 Hz rate, note that the DB insert takes some amount of time, so the one-second sleep means each cycle takes dbtime+1 second and you will steadily fall behind.  If the DB interaction is reliably less than a second, you can modify the sleep to adjust for the next one-second interval.

```
loop do
  run_db_insert
  sleep(Time.now.to_f.ceil - Time.now.to_f)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple loop with `sleep` command should do the job.

```
while true
    # do stuff here
    sleep 1 # wait one second
end
```